# Rails for Django developers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am used to using Django for some time now. Now I have to learn some RoR. Are there any good RoR tutorials that explain things in terms someone used to Django would understand, ie, is there a "polls" tutorial for RoR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love "[Creating a weblog in 15 minutes with Rails 2](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts)." Some of the code is outdated, but you will quickly learn how Rails MVC code is organized.